# start a activity in CountDownTimer class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, countdowntimer

i create a CountDownTimer class but i don't know how give value for context
error for  this code:

```
public class Timer extends CountDownTimer {
```

.
.
.

```
  @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        timeTextView.setText("Compeleted");


        try {
            Intent i = new Intent(this.context,eghbalpoor.ir.vaghteesterahat.activities.AlertDialog.class);


  i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);



    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e("ERROR", e.toString());
    }
}
```

}
`

Comment: Pass a `Context` as a constructor param from your `Activity` and call `startActivity()` on that instance.

Comment: @user13 you are right, my timer class was anonymous class inside the activity. Sorry :D The way you suggested will work then.